# createMessageComponentCollector is not a function. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm writing my discord music bot and I'm trying to handle button presses via createMessageComponentCollector, but I'm getting the error `createMessageComponentCollector is not a function`
Code example:

```
// player.textChannel is channel id
    const nplaying = await client.channels.cache.get(player.textChannel).send({ embeds: [embed], components: [row, row2] });
    
    const filter = (message) => {
      if(message.guild.me.voice.channel && message.guild.me.voice.channelId === message.member.voice.channelId) return true;
      else {
        const msg = message.reply({ embeds: "You need be in vc", ephemeral: true });
        setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 5000);
      }
    };
    const collector = nplaying.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, time: player.current.length });

// player.current.length - track length
    collector.on('collect', async (message) => {...
```

Comment: Did you try logging the `nplaying` object and seeing what it is? The function should exist on the message object that is returned by the `send` function. Are you using an old version of discord.js?

Comment: i use actual version of d.js. v13